# Custom PHP error handler

Tags: php, class

I have tried to find s better PHP error handler, one that will be easier to read in html, but I don't see any on google.

I tried to make my own, but the task of figuring out the commands was more than I had time for and I ran into many errors.

Here is the garbage that php is producing right now (files, classes and function names have been changed):

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare bbb() (previously declared in /home/user/path/1.php:5) in /home/user/path/1.php on line 26 Call Stack: 0.0309 662280 1. {main}() /home/user/path/1.php:0 0.0610 5610272 2. su::aaa() /home/user/path/1.php:21 0.0610 5610752 3. su::__callStatic() /home/user/path/class.su.php:0 0.0610 5611456 4. call_user_func_array() /home/user/path/class.su.php:27 0.0610 5611912 5. user->aaa() /home/user/path/class.su.php:0 0.0628 5670816 6. user->aaa() /home/user/path/class.user.php:3342 0.0628 5671640 7. user->aaa() /home/user/path/class.user.php:3407 0.0628 5672464 8. user->sss() /home/user/path/class.user.php:3449 0.0628 5679576 9. DA->ccc() /home/user/path/class.user.php:3475
```

It is all one line and I can't parse it well in my head to see what is actually happening. I want though this call stack to be printed as nice html.

Thanks,
Elijah

Comment: php and error handling is a funny story, just the ending is more like a crime story: many parts of php still don't throw exceptions or at least something that is catchable, but terminate the execution.

Comment: Just press CTRL+U (no idea for apple) and you will see that the formatting of the backtrace is actually multiline. Also if that is for a test-system (as you need to see the errors in the browser and not logged), consider xdebug which gives you more flavored HTML backtraces and errors even incl. variabels and so on. http://xdebug.org/ <- go get it gadget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that I was looking for was debug_backtrace. By implementing this in the error handler, I was able to print the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`set_error_handler()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)** It's designed specifically for that. Define a function that accepts the following arguments:

```
handler_function ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] )
```

And have `set_error_handler()` to use that instead of the default PHP handler. Make sure to read the entire [manual entry](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) first!

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean implementation of what you want  http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php and can easily be customized

The Code

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (! (error_reporting () & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_USER_ERROR :
            echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
            echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
            echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
            exit ( 1 );
            break;

        case E_USER_WARNING :
            echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        case E_USER_NOTICE :
            echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        default :
            echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
```

If this is not what you want then explain better